# Can't start Eclipse from command line in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, bash, sudo, eclipse

If I double-click on the eclipse icon then Eclipse boots up, but for some reason when I navigate to the directory of Eclipse and run something like

```
sudo bash eclipse
```

I get the error that it can't execute a binary file.  Which is strange because why does double-clicking on it work then? :)

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the answer why and the command to do it correctly on various OS is here:

http://www.luisdelarosa.com/2004/10/27/how-to-run-eclipse-from-the-command-line-in-os-x-and-windows-and-linux/

Comment: You link is broken - a good example of why you shouldn't just link to answer but at least provide the gist of it....